# Is it possible to define table inside sql statement?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Is there a way to have a custom table inside select statement?

Something like this:

```
select id from (1, 2, 3, 4) tbl
```

Assuming `tbl` is alias and the custom table has one column with 1, 2, 3, 4 rows.

Is this possible without creating a physical temp table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it (*numbers table*) like that in *Oracle*:

```
 with tbl as (
          -- generates table with id column with 1, 2, 3, 4 values
      select level id
        from dual
  connect by level <= 4) 

  select id 
    from tbl
```

you can put the same in different syntax:

```
select id 
  from     (select level id
              from dual
        connect by level <= 4) tbl
```

if you need *arbitrary values*, say `1, 5, 14, 127` you can achieve it like that:

```
with tbl as (
     select 1 from dual
  union all 
     select 5 from dual
  union all 
     select 14 from dual
  union all 
     select 127 from dual
)

select id
  from tbl
```

Or

```
   select id
     from (select 1 from dual
            union all 
           select 5 from dual
            union all 
           select 14 from dual
            union all 
           select 127 from dual) tbl
```

If you want to have syntax like `from (1, 2, 3)` you have to declare a type

```
  create or replace type NumberTable is table of number;

  ...

  select *
    from table(NumberTable(1, 2, 3, 4)) tbl
```

Comment: The numbers need to be entered manually and not produced by a select from dual statement. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want to preserve the syntax from (1, 2, 3) as much as possible you have to create a type (see my edit)

Comment: what is that table function doing after from and why does it accept a custom type?

Comment: It converts the pl/sql collection NumberTable into an object that behaves like a regular table that you can use in a query

Comment: but those are two statements, I am seeking for all in select statement

Comment: The create type will only have to be executed once.

Comment: and later I can use select without create the type?

Comment: @devhedgehog Correct. Once the user defined type is created as a schema object you can use it in any session. An other option is to check if there is one in one of the standard packages (dbms_sql?) that you can use.

Comment: still I do not know what is that Table statement doing and why NumberTable type?

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace type char_int is table of integer;
/



with numbers as (select column_value
                 from table(char_int(1,2,5,6,7)))
select numbers.column_value
,           object_name
,           object_id
from all_objects
join numbers on (substr(object_id,1,1) = numbers.column_value); 
;
```

Output:

```
<snip>
    1   V$HS_AGENT  1999
    2   V$HS_SESSION    2001
<snip>
```